# Trying to pass core data from a tableView to a new view when row is selected - keep getting errors

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, segue, uitableview

I have been at this for a while - I am trying to pass data from a UITableView cell that uses core data to a new view.  I have tried many different variables within the prepare for Segue code but keep getting use of unresolved identifier error - see code below - what am I missing?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "myEventsCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyEventsTableViewCell

    let eventData = myEvents [indexPath.row]
    cell.eventNameLabel.text = "Name: " + eventData.eventName
    cell.startDateLabel.text = "Start: " + eventData.startDate
    cell.endDateLabel.text = "End: " + eventData.endDate

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue (segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showEventDetails" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as eventDetailView
            destinationController.eventNameLabel.text = "Name: " + eventData.eventName [indexPath.row]
            destinationController.eventStartLabel.text = "Start: " + eventData.startDate [indexPath.row]
            destinationController.eventEndLabel.text = "End: " + eventData.endDate [indexPath.row]
            destinationController.eventDetailLabel.text = eventData.details [indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't paraphrase errors; paste the actual error into your question. Also tell us where you get the error (which line if you know it).

Answer (score 0):

How does your segue know the object you want to transfer? You missed to call the object in a way like:

```
  let thisTask = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!)    as YOUROBJECT
```

or something else if you don't use NSFetchedResultController - for example:       let eventData = myEvents [indexPath]

Don't know how does your model look like so it is maybe not so precise...but for sure you miss to tell the segue which object it is.

Answer (score 0):

What is `eventData` in:

```
"Name: " + eventData.eventName [indexPath.row]
```

If your above code works why don't you use again the construct

```
let eventData = myEvents [indexPath.row]
```

and then

```
    destinationController.eventNameLabel.text = "Name: " + eventData.eventName
    /* code */
```

to access the values for your destination controller?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your error, I don't know if this is what's causing the error, but you can't set the text of a label in your destination controller like you're trying to do. At the time prepareForSegue is called, the destination controller has been instantiated, but its view has not yet been loaded. Thus, its outlets will be nil. You should create string properties in your destination view controller, and pass the strings to it. Populate the labels in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error has to do with eventData not being defined in prepareForSegue. A better approach to passing the data from the selected cell to the detail view controller is as follows:

```
// I assume you have an existing class eventData
class EventData {
    var eventName: String!
    // other properties
}

class MyEventsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var eventNameLabel: UILabel!
    // other outlets

    // Add this property to your tableview cell
    // Now your cell has a direct reference to the eventData, we will use that in the prepareForSegue function
    var eventData: EventData! {
        didSet {
            eventNameLabel.text = "Name: " + eventData.eventName
            // other properties
        }
    }

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "myEventsCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyEventsTableViewCell

    let eventData = myEvents [indexPath.row]

    // Here you can set the eventData for the cell, this will automatically set the outlets.
    cell.eventData = eventData

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    return cell
}



override func prepareForSegue (segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showEventDetails" {
        // The sender parameter represents the selected cell
        let selectedCell = sender! as MyEventsTableViewCell
        // now we have a reference to the eventData for this selected cell
        let eventData = selectedCell.eventData

        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as eventDetailView
        // we pass the eventData to the destinationController (you will have to add a eventData property to the destinationController)
        destinationController.eventData = eventData

    }
}
```

You should not directly access the outlets of the destinationController, as explained by @rdelmar. Instead create a property for eventData. When the destinationController view loads you can use that property to set the outlets of the detail view.

One more naming suggestion: your destination controller has class name eventDetailView. That is confusing, because it is not a view, but a viewcontroller. I would suggest to rename it to EventDetailViewController or something similar of your taste.

Comment: Thanks Peter this - was very helpful - I think I am close - but believe I am now missing something in the eventDetailView.  You mention setting up the property there which I have done but not sure now what else I am missing - I am getting an error when clicking into my detail view that says dynamiccastClass unconditional

Comment: This could be an unrelated issue, because until now you didn't get this far due to the previous errors. It's a bit of guesswork without having your code but there are some things to check. Does the class name in the storyboard match the class name of the detailVC? If the detailVC appears does it show the right event data?

Comment: this may be getting complicated but I will try and explain - I have a tableview controller - and within it I have a header view - this header view is what I am trying to populate with this data as the destination - so its not actually a view controller but a view within a tableviewcontroller - I have the class for the view set up as the class name - the tableViewcontroller is not coded yet so still is classed as UITableVIewController - is what I am trying to do with the segue code to go to a view as opposed to a view controller even possible?  if not, any suggestions?  thanks in advance

Comment: the intent of the tableview is to navigate the user to details of an event they created where it captures user entered comments, photos, checkins etc. which I will use the prototype cell for - which is why I am trying to grab the event details (name, start and end date) into the view as the header.  the source controller in this case is tableviewcontroller listing of user created events with name and dates